# FOSUserBundle changing text on page depending on form

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm very new to symfony2 and twig templating in general.

My question is related to the FOSUserBundle.

I have a base template which has 2 columns,  `{% block left %}` and `{% block right %}`

I have created a new file: `Base5/UserBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig`

which extends my 2 column layout

```
{%  extends '::base_2col.html.twig' %}

{% block left %}
    I want this text to change depending on wether a login form, register form, profile page etc is displayed
{% endblock %}

{% block right %}
    {{ block('fos_user_content') }}
{% endblock %}
```

as the actual form is rendered using `{{ block('fos_user_content') }}`, how can i change the text in the right panel depending on what form is displayed, ideally i want to use a different include, containing the various descriptions into texts for the diffirent form.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found out, just a question of duplicating the templates from the fosuserbundle views directory